# Can't edit joomla module, blank page with select

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

This is probably a difficult question because i can't give you a lot of information. When i open the edit screen in the adminside of a module it's being shown for a split second and the the page refreases to a blank page with a input type select.

[image]

I already tried to uninstal the admin template and reinstal but the issue is still here. It happens with any admin template i tried so far accept the oldschool Hathor admin template.

I have no idea where to look for the problem. I hope someone else encountered this issue before and has a solution. Or atleast an idea where to look.

Tell me if there is any information i can give you to clearify.

Kind regards, Jeroen

Comment: BTW I run the leatest joomla version 3.6.5.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because:
1.This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.
2.  this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network - namely the Joomla Q&A site at http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Comment: Instead of beating around the bush just let us know which module you are facing this issue.

Comment: Any module, doesnt matter. If i add or edit any module

Answer (score 0):

I Just fixed it by:

- Make a backup
- Clear all cache and fix database
- Reinstall Joomla core files Components -> Joomla -> install

available from Joomla 3.6.x